# How to use gateway with multiple lan

Tags: networking, dhcp, gateway

I try to create 3 LAN with different range on same gateway but I have a conflict in the dhcpd, can you help me to resolve my problem please ?

```
subnet 192.168.42.0 netmask 255.255.255.0{
      range 192.168.42.40 192.168.42.60;
      option broadcast-address 192.168.42.63;
      option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
}

subnet 192.168.42.64 netmask 255.255.255.0{
      range 192.168.42.70 192.168.42.110;
      option broadcast-address 192.168.42.127;
      option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
}

subnet 192.168.42.128 netmask 255.255.255.0{
      range 192.168.42.140 192.168.42.180;
      option broadcast-address 192.168.42.191;
      option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have some special reason for trying to squeeze in 3 different subnets within 255 addresses? I mean, don't you have the freedom to give them 255 addresses each? Like, make the subnets, say for example, 192.168.40.0/24 , 192.168.50.0/24 , and 192.168.60.0/24 ? Is there something that's forcing you to stay within the 192.168.42.nnn address range for all 3?

Comment: Interesting!  I keep seeing this same picture, with these same numbers, posted by numerous different people with different questions... That must be a homework assignment that was given to many people. :-))

Answer (score 0):

Find some subnet calculator on the Internet and count your masks.

255.255.255.0 is /24, which means the host part is 8 bits (32 bits - 24 bits). But from what you show you want them only 64 addresses long not 256.

Comment: I need to alter the mask ?

Comment: @rmarquet21 yes

Comment: @Pourko You should ask the questioner not me.